# Is there a way to send two udp streams over a xen paravirtualized system taking separate routes over 2 VMs to the same destination computer?

Tags: udp, virtual-machine, xen, measurement, virtual-network

I'm working on my second experiment for my master thesis and my supervisor had some requirements on this experiment and I don't really know how to proceed. Earlier I was thinking that it should be just to forward the packets but now facing the problem hands on I don't know where to begin.

The setup is Computer 1 ->Measurement point->System Under Test->Measurement point-> Computer2

The System Under Test consists of 2 VMs created with the XEN management tool XL.
There is a bridge from computer 1 on the interface "eth0" to "SUT" which is connected to the VM and the same thing on the otherside to computer 2.

I'm going to send 2 UDP streams and compare the timestamps over the measurement points with two servers on computer 2. The streams are going to be separated by port number and keyid for the stream.

My question is how do I make one of the UDP stream take the route through one of the VMs and the other UDP stream to take the other route?

Comment: I'm thinking about using IP tables and choosing VM based on the destination port.

Comment: What is the 'SUT'? Is it acting as a transparent bridge?  Or is it a router? How are the two VMs configured?  The most straightforward way I can think is if you have two subnets, two network interfaces, on both computer 1 and computer 2 and connect each network through one VM...

Comment: The SUT is acting as a forwarding "router" so that computer 1 knows computer 2 through the VM.
The VMs are configured with iptables turned of, ipforwarding on with two interfaces. One to computer 1 and one to computer 2.

Hm that sounds good, to ceate an extra interface on both the computers and then dividing the two connections by subnets.